# How to show one values in select options while passing to state other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, drop-down-menu, use-state

So I need to show "Yes" or "No" in the dropdown, but to pass "admin" or "member" to api.
Right now I'm doing it via ternary operator, checking either e.target.value or I also checked state "role" when passing it to api request, and it worked. But is there any other, nicer and more reliable way?

```
 export function EditableRole({
      employee,
      onSave,
      onCancel,
    }: EditableRoleProps) {

  const [role, setRole] = useState("MEMBER");

  const handleSave = () => api.updateUser(role)


  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapperEditable}>
      <Dropdown
        className={styles.dropdownRole}
        options={["Yes", "No"]}
        value={role}
        onChange={(e) =>
          setRole(e.target.value === "Yes" ? Role.ADMIN : Role.MEMBER)
        }
      />
      <Icon name="tick" onClick={() => handleSave()} />
      <Icon name="cancel" onClick={onCancel} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below is my Dropdown component:

```
export interface DropdownProps {
  label?: string;
  id?: string;
  options: string[];
  value: string;
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
  className?: any;
}

export function Dropdown({
  label,
  id,
  options,
  onChange,
  className,
}: DropdownProps) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <label className={styles.labeltext} htmlFor={id}>
        {label}
      </label>
      <select
        id={id}
        className={cx(className, styles.dropdown)}
        onChange={onChange}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option}>{option}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The `value` and the label need not be the same. Show your `Dropdown` component for more help. In plain HTML `<option value=Role.ADMIN>Yes</option>` but without knowing how your Dropdown handles creating `<option>` elements there's no way to help.

Comment: Thank you so much! I updated my question and included `Dropdown` code and I think what you suggested is going to work, I'm going to check now

Comment: It looks like you could pass an array of objects for `options` with `[{label: 'Yes', value: Role.ADMIN}, {label: 'No', value: Role.Member}]` and then handle setting value and option text appropriately `{options.map(({value, label}) => (<option key={value} value={value}>{label}</option> ...`